# Can't reinstall ettercap files in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, aptitude

I can't reinstall ettercap files. I try to reinstall with

```
apt-get install ettercap-graphical
apt-get install --reinstall ettercap-graphical
aptitude install ettercap-graphical
```

I can install but when execute `ettercap -G` said this error

```
ERROR : 2, No such file or directory
[/build/ettercap-PdV7vU/ettercap-0.8.0/src/ec_conf.c:load_conf:255]

Cannot open etter.conf
```

and when I execute `locate etter.conf` or `find / -name etter.conf` it's not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall  ettercap-text-only  ettercap-graphical ettercap-common
```

Comment: i worrk with apt-get update